# Scala 2 futures containing api calls race condition

Tags: api, scala, playframework

I've defined some API calls in Futures that make API calls to Mashery and Stripe

```
 val stripeFuture = Future { // api call }
 val masheryFuture = Future { //api call }
```

For the stripeFuture -The main logic is to set the **stripeCustomerId** on a **Client object** within the onSuccess block

```
  stripeFuture onSuccess {
       //client.stripeCustomerId
  }
```

I've wrapped up the API calls in a for-comprehension similar to the example in [Futures and Promises](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html)

```
  val apiCalls = for {

      masheryInfo <- masheryFuture
      stripeCustomer <- stripeFuture
    }
```

There is a rollback if one of the API calls fail

```
  apiCalls onFailure {
      case pse: MasheryException => {
        // delete stripe customer id
   }

   case e: StripeException => {
       //delete mashery api key
   }
```

The problem is when the call to Mashery fails 'masheryFuture', I want to rollback **'get the stripe id'** from the Client object but there is a around a 1 second delay til that call finishes and it **doesn't set the stripeCustomerId** until it hits the onSuccess block so within the ase pse: MasheryException => { } block, **client.getstripeCustomerId returns null**.

Is there a way of getting around this race condition for both of the API calls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Future.andThen`.

The doc:

> Applies the side-effecting function to the result of this future, and
>   returns a new future with the result of this future.
>
> This method allows one to enforce that the callbacks are executed in a
>   specified order.

`for (f <- Future(x).andThen { y })` etc.

Update:

```
for (f <- Future(x) andThen {
    case Success(x) => use(x)
    case _ => // ignore
  }) yield result
```

Comment: "Style" comment: this calls for the "dot-free" notation: `for (f <- Future(x) andThen { y })`

Comment: @RandallSchulz Absolutely.  I didn't want to impose my lifestyle on others.  I don't remember the last time I used a dot. In California, it's legal to go dotless in public.

Comment: @som-snytt How would I apply it in the case above? andThen needs a Try as a param?

Comment: @unleashed you mean how do I do something only if it succeeded?